# Console powers off and powers on in quick succession. Insufficient current? Voltage drop?

Tags: usb, power-supply, hdmi, voltage

I have a question about a specific setup I have.

I have a Nintendo Classic Mini console, this console:

- requires 5V/1A through its USB 2.0 micro-B female connector to power the console
- outputs through HDMI

Normally a person would connect the provided 1.5 m long passive USB 2.0 cable (male type A on one end, micro-B male on the other) to a laptop and the console and the HDMI cable to the console and a TV.

My setup is more complex, however:

- a power supply goes into AC power socket

  - outputs 5V/1A through its sole female type A USB port
- an active USB extension cable

  - 5 meters
  - male type A <> female type A
  - FE 1.1 chipset
  - **goes into the power supply female type A USB port**
  - http://www.delock.com/produkte/F_172_Stecker-A---Stecker-B--aktiv_82308/merkmale.html
- a passive USB 2.0 cable

  - provided with the console
  - 1.5 meters
  - male type A <> male micro-B
  - **goes into the extension cable and into the console**
- a "HDMI to VGA plus audio converter"

  - http://www.delock.com/produkte/S_65587/merkmale.html
  - CH7101 chipset
  - **goes into the console on one side (HDMI side) and on the other side:**
  - speakers (with their own power supply) are connected with the 3.5 jack
  - a monitor is connected with a 5 meter cable - male VGA connector on both sides of the cable

When I turn on the console, sometimes it might work ok, but sometimes it turns off after a few seconds, then turns on again, then turns off again, etc.

I am trying to understand the situation, why does the console power off and on in quick succession:

- Is it because the chipset in "HDMI to VGA plus audio converter" also requires current and the 5V/1A power supply doesn't provide enough? (Console itself needs 1A)

  - If the converter requires power, it can only be provided through the HDMI end, correct? Devices connected to the VGA and 3.5 jack cannot provide power to the converter
- Is it because of voltage drop between the power supply and the console? (5 m active USB cable + 1.5 m passive USB cable = 6.5 m between the power supply and the console)
- Some other reason?

Comment: So some other source told me, that not only the converter needs current, but also the USB active cable's chipset (makes sense).
So basically the 5V/1A power source is not enough, power source with more current is required.
Only thing that bothers me is that the manufacturer of the USB active cable and the HDMI/VGA+audio converter doesn't supply any information about how much current these devices require - this means I have to guess what power supply, with how much extra output current, do I require.

Comment: One more information:
The 5 meter active USB extension cable can have only 500 mA through it.
So my configuration is impossible to make work, it seems.